# Copy row into new spreadsheet based on unique identifier

Tags: vba, excel

In the tab `Paste New IDs Here` column A, starting at row 2, has a list of unique IDs used to identify a person. There are thirty unique ID numbers.

In the `Raw Export` tab, there's a bunch of raw data, where column B, starting at row 2, has all the IDs for 200+ people.

I am putting a list of ID numbers in `Paste New IDs Here` and pulling the entire row associated with that ID number into `Test`. Therefore, only rows that have ID numbers specified in the `Paste New IDs Here` sheet will be copied into `Test`.

Only ten rows (out of the thirty) are being generated.

Do I need another loop?

```
Sub ExtractID()

Set i = Sheets("Raw Export")
Set e = Sheets("Test")
Set p = Sheets("Paste New IDs Here")

Dim d
Dim j
Dim k

d = 1
j = 2
k = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("B" & j))

If i.Range("B" & j) = p.Range("A" & k) Then
d = d + 1
k = k + 1
e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value


End If
j = j + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do that in a very efficient way just with Excel. With some vlookup function you should be able to setup a sheet in which as soon as you paste the IDs in a specific column, Excel retrieve the corresponding data and display them. And when you delete the IDs, corresponding data are no longer displayed. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Louis.B This was my initial goal, but after spending a lot of time researching I was made to believe using VBA was the only way to go. I got it working using VBA, but I would still like to explore this option. Any idea on how I can use VLOOKUP to copy an entire row?

Comment: The idea is not to "copy" the entire row with `vlookup` but rather to use `vlookup` to retrieve data in each column you want. Just to give you an idea, something like that should work : `=vlookup("Paste New IDs Here"!A"correspoding row" ; "Raw Export"!DataSet ; correponding column)`. You can even add the appropriate if condition to display nothing if the vlookup return some error. Tell me if you need more detail I can add an answer about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an inner loop over k:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("B" & j))    
  Do Until isEmpty(p.Range("A"&k))
    If i.Range("B" & j) = p.Range("A" & k) Then
      d = d + 1          
      e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value
    End If
    k = k + 1
  Loop
  k=2
  j = j + 1    
Loop
```